# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored with oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I try to compile the function but they show the error "PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" and mention the function "PO_PROD_CODE".
Could you please help to give some comment.

> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored with oracle function (Function "PO_PROD_CODE")

```
  FUNCTION PO_PROD_CODE (s_prod_code VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

   v_po_prod_code_result   VARCHAR2(100);

   BEGIN 

     SELECT FLEX_VALUE 
        INTO v_po_prod_code_result
      FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL

    WHERE  attribute1 IN ('BXX', 'EXX', 'GXX', 'HKXX', 'PDX', 'PSX', 'GPX') 
      AND FLEX_VALUE = s_prod_code ;

  RETURN v_po_prod_code_result;
  END;
  /

   FUNCTION PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT (N_ORG_ID NUMBER, N_PO_HEADER_ID NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  v_po_doc_location_text  VARCHAR2(150);                                      
  s_prod_code VARCHAR2(20); 
   BEGIN

      SELECT 'PO\'||PO_DIVISION_CODE||'\'||PO_PRODUCT_LINE||'\'||PO_NUM||'\' AS "DOC_TEXT"
        INTO v_po_doc_location_text
        FROM (SELECT  poh.SEGMENT1 PO_NUM,
                      poh.ORG_ID,
                      poh.ATTRIBUTE14 AS "PO_PRODUCT_LINE",
                      poh.ATTRIBUTE15 AS "PO_DIVISION",
            CASE (SELECT ffvv.attribute1 bs_group
                        FROM apps.fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv,
                            apps.fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs
                        WHERE ffvv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
                            AND ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXX_PROD_LINES'
                            AND ffvv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
                            AND ((ffvv.attribute4 = 'Y' AND poh.ORG_ID = 83) OR (ffvv.attribute5 = 'Y' AND poh.ORG_ID = 87))
                            AND ffvv.flex_value = PO_PROD_CODE (v_po_prod_code_result, s_prod_code) --call the "PO_PROD_CODE" function get the sql feild "prod_line_code")

                                  WHEN 'ABC'    THEN 'AB'   --FLEX_VALUE_ID,FLEX_VALUE PRO_CODE,
                                  WHEN 'DEF'    THEN 'DE'
                                  WHEN 'GSD'    THEN 'HK'
                                  WHEN 'HIG'    THEN 'HG'
                                  WHEN 'PIG'    THEN 'PG'
                                  WHEN 'BCE'    THEN 'BE'
                                  WHEN 'GP'     THEN 'HK' 

                                  ELSE ''
                                 END PO_DIVISION_CODE  
                FROM APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL poh
                WHERE poh.ORG_ID = N_ORG_ID
                  AND poh.po_header_id = N_PO_HEADER_ID

       );

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_po_doc_location_text := 'PO\MO\';
    END;
    RETURN v_po_doc_location_text + s_prod_code;
END;
```

Complie success!
 When I try to run the script, the detail as follow:

```
SELECT abc.XXX_util.PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT ('83','1145225') from dual;
```

The error message said

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Comment: You need to examine, and show us if necessary, the entire error message stack. But the query in your first function has two `FROM` clauses (which are different tables). You also haven't shown the `CREATE` part - are these supposed to be two standalone functions, or part of a package? (You don't have slashes *inside* a package.)

Comment: hi Alex, thanks for your mention. the script has been updated.

Comment: What are those `WHEN-THEN` comparisons supposed to do in your query? You have not written any `CASE` statement. Please elaborate (and modify the code in question)

Comment: Hi, Goran, The "WHEN-THEN" result as 1. "ABC" -> "AB"  2. "DEF" -> DE etc. The result for change the text data and fulfill the network drive path. Example: PO\AB\BXX\1234567

Answer (score 1):

It is not `FROM ... INTO`, but `INTO ... FROM`:

```
FUNCTION PO_PROD_CODE (s_prod_code VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   v_po_prod_code_result   VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN 
     SELECT FLEX_VALUE 
      FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL           --> this is
      INTO v_po_prod_code_result             --> wrong
    WHERE  attribute1 IN ('BXX', 'EXX', 'GXX', 'HKXX', 'PDX', 'PSX', 'GPX') 
      AND FLEX_VALUE = s_prod_code ;
  RETURN v_po_prod_code_result;
END;
/
```

Should be

```
     SELECT FLEX_VALUE 
      INTO v_po_prod_code_result             
      FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
```

**[EDIT]**

The second function's CASE is invalid. That SELECT should be moved out of it, its tables used in main SELECT's FROM clause. Something like this (which is OK in syntax, I don't know whether it'll work):

```
FUNCTION PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT (N_ORG_ID NUMBER, N_PO_HEADER_ID NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_po_doc_location_text  VARCHAR2 (150);
BEGIN
   SELECT    'PO\'
          || PO_DIVISION_CODE
          || '\'
          || PO_PRODUCT_LINE
          || '\'
          || PO_NUM
          || '\'
             AS "DOC_TEXT"
     INTO v_po_doc_location_text
     FROM (SELECT poh.SEGMENT1 PO_NUM,
                  poh.ORG_ID,
                  poh.ATTRIBUTE14 AS "PO_PRODUCT_LINE",
                  poh.ATTRIBUTE15 AS "PO_DIVISION",
                  CASE ffvv.attribute1
                     WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'AB' --FLEX_VALUE_ID,FLEX_VALUE PRO_CODE,
                     WHEN 'DEF' THEN 'DE'
                     WHEN 'GSD' THEN 'HK'
                     WHEN 'HIG' THEN 'HG'
                     WHEN 'PIG' THEN 'PG'
                     WHEN 'BCE' THEN 'BE'
                     WHEN 'GP' THEN 'HK'
                     ELSE ''
                  END
                     PO_DIVISION_CODE
             FROM APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL poh,
                  apps.fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv,
                  apps.fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs
            WHERE     ffvv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
                  AND ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXX_PROD_LINES'
                  AND ffvv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
                  AND (   (    ffvv.attribute4 = 'Y'
                           AND poh.ORG_ID = 83)
                       OR (    ffvv.attribute5 = 'Y'
                           AND poh.ORG_ID = 87))
                  AND ffvv.flex_value =
                         PO_PROD_CODE (v_po_prod_code_result, s_prod_code)
                  AND poh.ORG_ID = N_ORG_ID
                  AND poh.po_header_id = N_PO_HEADER_ID);

   RETURN v_po_doc_location_text;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      v_po_doc_location_text   := 'PO\MO\';
END;
```

Comment: May I know the "s_prod_code" need to define more? The error to mentioned the function "PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT"    and ffvv.flex_value = PO_PROD_CODE (v_po_prod_code_result, s_prod_code) <- PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "S_PROD_CODE": invalid identifier

Comment: The error "PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "S_PROD_CODE": invalid identifier" is still to show on screen>

Comment: So, what is S_PROD_CODE? You passed it to the function as `PO_PROD_CODE (v_po_prod_code_result, s_prod_code)`. I don't have your tables, I don't know whether you posted everything you wrote or not. You should know what S_PROD_CODE is and fix it. How? That's called *debugging*.

Comment: The table as apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL <- oracle table and get the field "FLEX_VALUE" result.

Comment: Are you saying that it is an Oracle Apps. table? I don't have Oracle Apps. Those are just *table names* to me, I've never seen them before.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for all support me. I just to found the function cannot be compile issue on the variable is not to declare but the other issue to said "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error". Could you please help to check the update script?

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code and you'll have to correct them all:

- You're supposed to write the `SELECT INTO` statement by writing the `INTO` part before writing the `FROM` (as you have written in your PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT function)
- Your `WHEN-THEN` comparisons are missing the `CASE` word
- In your PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT function you have called your PO_PROD_CODE function by passing two parameters, but it only accepts one parameter. You should only pass input parameter. If you want to fill local variable with the returning value from PO_PROD_CODE function, you should do it outside of SQL query.
- You are missing one `)` bracket in your query inside PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT function and I guess it's the one that got lost inside your `call the "PO_PROD_CODE" function get the sql feild "prod_line_code"` comment
- You're ending your PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT function before the `RETURN` statement. You should add one more `BEGIN` before your `SELECT INTO`

I can also see that your PO_PROD_CODE function (as it's now written) always returns the input value (`s_prod_code`). 
It's selecting `fnd_flex_values_vl.flex_value` into return variable just after saying that the very same `flex_value` must be equal to `s_prod_code`, which is your function's input parameter.

I guess this is the way you intended your code to be like:

```
FUNCTION PO_PROD_CODE (s_prod_code VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_po_prod_code_result   VARCHAR2 (100);

BEGIN
    SELECT flex_value
      INTO v_po_prod_code_result
      FROM apps.fnd_flex_values_vl
     WHERE     attribute1 IN ('BXX',
                              'EXX',
                              'GXX',
                              'HKXX',
                              'PDX',
                              'PSX',
                              'GPX')
           AND flex_value = s_prod_code; -- STILL JUST RETURNS THE INPUT PARAMETER

    RETURN v_po_prod_code_result;
END;
/

FUNCTION PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT (N_ORG_ID NUMBER, N_PO_HEADER_ID NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_po_doc_location_text   VARCHAR2 (150);
    s_prod_code VARCHAR2(20); -- NEEDS TO HAVE SOME VALUE ASSIGNED BEFORE PASSING IT TO "PO_PROD_CODE" FUNCTION BELOW IN CODE

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'PO\' || PO_DIVISION_CODE || '\' || PO_PRODUCT_LINE || '\' || PO_NUM || '\' AS "DOC_TEXT"
          INTO v_po_doc_location_text
          FROM (SELECT poh.SEGMENT1 PO_NUM,
                       poh.ORG_ID,
                       poh.ATTRIBUTE14 AS "PO_PRODUCT_LINE",
                       poh.ATTRIBUTE15 AS "PO_DIVISION",
                       CASE (SELECT ffvv.attribute1 bs_group
                               FROM apps.fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv, apps.fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs
                              WHERE     ffvv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
                                    AND ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXX_PROD_LINES'
                                    AND ffvv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
                                    AND ( (ffvv.attribute4 = 'Y' AND poh.ORG_ID = 83) OR (ffvv.attribute5 = 'Y' AND poh.ORG_ID = 87))
                                    AND ffvv.flex_value = PO_PROD_CODE (s_prod_code) --call the "PO_PROD_CODE" function get the sql feild "prod_line_code", "v_po_prod_code_result" removed because PO_PROD_CODE expects only one parameter and because only input parameters can be written here
                                                                                                           )
                           WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'AB' --FLEX_VALUE_ID,FLEX_VALUE PRO_CODE,
                           WHEN 'DEF' THEN 'DE'
                           WHEN 'GSD' THEN 'HK'
                           WHEN 'HIG' THEN 'HG'
                           WHEN 'PIG' THEN 'PG'
                           WHEN 'BCE' THEN 'BE'
                           WHEN 'GP' THEN 'HK'
                           ELSE ''
                       END
                           PO_DIVISION_CODE
                  FROM APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL poh
                 WHERE poh.ORG_ID = N_ORG_ID AND poh.po_header_id = N_PO_HEADER_ID);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            v_po_doc_location_text := 'PO\MO\';
    END;

    RETURN v_po_doc_location_text;
END;
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: Hi, Goran. The function (PO_PROD_CODE) will get the sql field result and compare with function (PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT). When the result is match, the PO path will generated.

Comment: @Andy, I understand you're trying to generate the concatenated path string, but in order to do so you'll have to resolve all of the errors I stated in my answer so that your function can successfully compile

Comment: @Andy , I spotted some more errors in your code and I figured out what you intended with your `CASE` statement in PO_DOC_LOCATION_TEXT function. I edited my answer with recommended code. See if that helps!

Comment: @Andy I edited the code in my answer now. Please look at the edits and take notion of the comments I wrote by them